# Who wins the poker hand if there are 5A's on table?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy

So I was watching this song by Adam Levin where Adam had 2K's and SZA had 2A's. And the table had 5A's, I thought in this case it should be a tie and they both will split equally. But it seems from the [video(What lover's do at 2:31)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Wiio4KoGe8&t=150s) like Levin lost. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

So firstly it's a music video, and whatever they're doing isn't poker. However if somehow you're playing some game with a joker wildcard, poker is a 5 card game, 5 aces would win. Both players have 5 aces, CHOP IT UP!

Comment: `Then the couple ends up at a card game, which I assume is poker and by the looks of it, played with several packs of cards. 5 aces are already on the table and SZA has two more aces with her. That is a brain-flush!`

Source : https://justrandomthings.com/2017/09/28/watch-bizarre-what-lovers-video-maroon-5-ft-sza-review/

Also which poker game is played with more than 1 deck?

Comment: Any game using two decks is not poker. Poker as we know it, hand rankings, etc are all based on a single deck. I don't know of any poker games that use two decks. I've dealt and heard of jokers added for wild cards, and short deck but not multiple decks.

Comment: TBH it's just creative license in the song. The director probably just figured that looked like a bad beat or something cool to put in to convey the message they wanted to.